# Asking a group of people about something

Tags: kanji, syntax, word-order

I want to know if this is even near to being correct. Basically I'm making a question to people who like pizza despite not knowing much about it. (You can replace pizza with anything)

> あまり知らない人、 あなた達に質問があります:  何故はピザが好きですか。

I assumed to used "達" since it's a plural suffix. 
"あまり知らない人" is how this group of people label themselves.
The question sentence I used, specially the structure, is the first that i could thinked of.

Comment: What do you want to say (in English)? And do you mean there is a group of people who call themselves あまり知らない人? I can hardly believe that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is unnatural. When we speak to strangers, we usually omit the pronoun and say すいません or ちょっといいですか, etc.

I correct your sentence as すいません、ちょっと質問してもいいですか? (あなた方は)何故ピザが好きなんですか?

However they obviously seem to be younger than you, you can use 君たち or あなたたち like 君たち(あなたたち), ちょっと質問してもいいかな? 君たち(あなたたち)は何故ピザが好きなの?